# WSO2 Identity Server 5.7.0 Oauth/OpenId Connect Logout has Error about session state?

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, openid-connect, logout, wso2-identity-server

WSO2 Identity Server 5.7.0 Oauth/OpenId Connect Logout has Error about session state?

this is my error:

```
access_denied opbs cookie not received Missing session state.
```

and this is my code:

```
 client = new HttpClient();
 var response3 = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:9443/oidc/logout?id_token_hint=" + id_token + "&post_logout_redirect_uri=http://localhost:49545/Home/Contact");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This logout request has to be sent via the browser. If you sent the logout request as a backend request, the relevant cookies will not be passed and the logout will not be processed correctly since WSO2 IS is looking for the the cookies in order to proceed.

Comment: How Can Send cookie with code?  I should Do it with c# code.can you help me How can use this in code?

Comment: No, the idea is to send the logout request from the browser itself without making the request from backend. So the cookies will be automatically included in the request.